# mac os x mavericks eclipse start and tip a directory not a file

Tags: eclipse, macos

I update mac to mavericks and found eclipse(adt bundle) can't start directly, and I check in terminal,found eclipse is a directory:

```
adt-bundle/eclipse/Eclipse.app/
```

and I can start in terminal:

```
adt-bundle/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

why?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Mavericks specifically; all OS X applications are supposed to be packaged like this, with the `.app` actually being a directory. If you look at any other standard OS X application you will find it is also a directory (although Finder hides this fact from you).

The reason Eclipse did not start directly must be some other reason.

Comment: how to lancher x.app and can view log

Comment: you are right .After install java runtime, and which can start directly, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Well, it's solved now, but it might have been something to do with the PATH in your terminal environment, being able to find Java.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should set the execute permission for the app. Execute this command in terminal:

chmod +x /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Then you can run the app as usually, clicking on Eclipse.app.